# Passing C# Date to SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, date

I have a problem with inserting a date time from my web app, using C# to my database with SQL Server 2008.

My machine is set to Hebrew but I also tried to change to `en-us` culture. It's a conversion thing I know, but can't figure out how to pass it correctly.

In the database, the column is declared as `DATE NOT NULL`,

This is how I try to pass a date from C# by using a dataset:

```
newDR["Close_Date"] = Convert.ToString(this.closeDate.Date.ToString("YYYYMMDD"));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `newDR["Close_Date"] = this.closeDate.Date;` doesn't work?

Answer (score 8):

Don't convert it to a string at all. Keep it as a `DateTime`. Try to avoid using string conversions as far as you can - every string conversion is a potential source of problems.

So:

```
newDR["Close_Date"] = closeDate.Date;
```